# MCPE multiplayer doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I open it from the world menu, when you press on play on the main menu, it says the multiplayer is on. When I go inside the world, the multiplayer button is off and grayed out.

Comment: I'm not sure how MCPE works, but on PC you have to open the world to LAN. Is there a MCPE equivalent that you could try

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually change if the game is multiplayer or not while you are playing that world. What you'll have to do, is exit out of the world, click the pencil icon next to it, go down to multiplayer, and then you can select "On/Off"

Answer (score 0):

The main menu multiplayer settings are the default and can be changed by a per world basis. You can't change this setting in game. Change it at the world list.